# How to rewrite from C# to Javascript? this._ Stamp = System.DateTime.Now.Subtract(start);

Tags: javascript, c#, url-rewriting

does someone know how I can rewrite this line from C# to Javascript?

```
this._ Stamp = System.DateTime.Now.Subtract(start);
```

start is from `System.DateTime`

Comment: This is doable in javascript, you just have to tell us what format you want the output to be (milliseconds, days, ...). BTW, use a library (like [**moment js**](https://momentjs.com/)), it gives you a lot of flexibility dealing with dates and times. Here is the method of which you can substract dates in momentjs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/

Comment: We can certainly tell you how to subtract dates in JavaScript!

Comment: Output should be like this 25.12.2015 0:00:00...

Answer (score 0):

Given a `start` date of:

`let start = new Date('2020/12/12');`

Then this is the equivalent of the C# statement:

`var stamp = new Date(Date.now - (Math.abs(new Date() - start)));`

Where `stamp` is the date represented by the subtracted date.

```js
let start = new Date('2020-12-12T00:00:00Z');
var stamp = new Date(Date.now() - (Math.abs(new Date() - start)));
console.log(stamp);
```

Comment: But what is when my start is definded as 12.12.2020 0:00:00 ? its date not a string

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - are you saying your starting date is represented as the string '12.12.2020 0:00:00' ?

Comment: Javascript dates are a pain in the _"lower back"_.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - Yes, You are correct, but _moment_ is not required for everything.

Comment: No, the start value has a date format. I just thought that you are using a string in your example...

Comment: As long as the date is a valid ISO date string it will work. I'll update the example with an ISO string. https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html